# Where is the gateway router for my cellular network

Tags: networking, ip, router

Please correct me if I am wrong.

If I connect my mobile phone to my router through wifi, then my router acts as a gateway to the internet.

In that case if I am using my cellular internet network on my mobile, now where is my gateway router? Is it at the cell tower?

Or someone please provide me with a resource on understanding how cell towers works on distributing ip adresses.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

it depends on type of network you’re running on (2G/3G/4G/5G) but in the grand scheme of things the gateway will NOT be the actual cell / tower that is handling your mobile coverage.

Further read depends on what type of network you’re looking for, but you can start reading about GPRS, UMTS, SGSN, GGSN, Node B, RNCs, etc, etc. Those are mostly components of 2G/3G networks but it will give you some starting point.